# how can i create PayPalAdvancedPayment object in order to make a chained payment?

Tags: android, paypal

i saw in here https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_android.pdf
on page 13.
the creation of the PayPalAdvancedPayment object?
when i copy the papyal jar to my libs folder i can't create an instance of it.

```
my code looks like this: 

private PayPalPayment getThingToBuy(String paymentIntent) {

    return new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1.75"), "USD", "hipster jeans",
            paymentIntent);

}
```

what i want is this:

```
PayPalReceiverDetails receiver0, receiver1;
receiver0 = new PayPalReceiverDetails();
…
//setup receiver details
…
PayPalAdvancedPayment advPayment = new PayPalAdvancedPayment();
advPayment.setCurrency("USD");
advPayment.getReceivers().add(receiver0);
advPayment.getReceivers().add(receiver1);
Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(advPayment, this);
this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
```

tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the [PayPal Android SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/) does not yet support chained or parallel payments.  The code snippet you pasted in the second section refers to the old [MPL](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/), which is your only option at this point.  Please follow the [iOS issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/9) on when the REST APIs and PayPal mSDK will be supporting this feature.